# How to shift the rowlabels from right to left in heatmap2 in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap, gplots

[image]

So I want to shift the rowlabels appearing on the right to left.

Comment: Please provide some dummy data or codes with which the plot can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

in your plotting function set

```
 plot(...,axes=FALSE)
```

so that you can define your own axes now
after that use the axis functions to set your own axis.

by default axis in this case y axis should be on the left anyway.
so you just get to the default settings
clear ls()
and clear your environment draw up again.

Comment: Hope you had read my question fully. I am using a heatmap2 here, for which the default is set to right and there is no axes parameter to heatmap2.